# Fieldset legend doesn't show properly when overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a fieldset with a legend on it like the following

```
<fieldset class="fieldsetStyle">
            <legend class="fieldsetLegendStyle">

                <div>
                     <h:outputText value="#{msgs.LABEL_AJOUTER_UTILISATEUR}"
                         rendered="#{gProfilCtrl.newUtilisateur}"/>
                     <h:outputText value="#{msgs.LABEL_MODIFIER_UTILISATEUR}"
                         rendered="#{!gProfilCtrl.newUtilisateur}"/>
                </div>

            </legend>
.
.
.
</fieldset>
```

when i set `overflow` property to `auto` in my CSS file the legend doesn't show properly. the top border disappear and this only in Chrome browser. firefox and IE work perfectly.

[image]

this is my css description:

```
.fieldsetStyle {
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    border: 1px solid #bed6f8;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    width: calc(100% - 37px);
    margin-right: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.fieldsetLegendStyle {
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #BED6F8;
    min-width: 199px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}
```

any ideas ?

**UPDATE**

when i don't set `overflow:auto` my panel overflows from the fieldset box.

[image]

Comment: Remove `overflow: auto;` seems to be working - http://jsfiddle.net/wmf448Ls/

Comment: i need to set overflow because sometimes the content overflows my fieldset's box.

Comment: How about wrap <fieldset> into a <div> and set the overflow:auto on the div?

Comment: I just wrapped the <fieldset> with a <div> without setting the overflow:auto fixed the issue. thank you.

Comment: Great! form elements are difficult for styling in general especially when dealing with cross browsers and OSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to wrap `<fieldset>` into a `<div>` and set the related styles on the div element.

Or perhaps, you can move the `<legend>` down one pixel to make the top border to appear.

```
.fieldsetLegendStyle {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```